# Some further explanation on a summation

Tags: summation

I am having a bit of trouble with this passage in the summation, could you guys help understand what's happening?

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i\leq{n}}({\frac{2}{3}})^n=\frac{3}{4}(\frac{2}{3})^i$$

Is it a purely algebraic passage or is it something more related to the problem I am currently doing

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The way in which this expression is written seems very unusual.  It is unclear if this was meant to be with $i$ as the indexing variable for the summation or if $n$ is.  If it was $i$ as the indexing variable (*which is the more common since it appears first in the condition*) then it is strange that $n$ appears in the expression for the summands and stranger still that the final result on the right hand side involves $i$ and not $n$.  This implies to me that $n$ would have been the indexing variable... If that were the case then write as $\frac14\sum\limits_{n=i}^\infty\left(\frac23\right)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{n\geq i}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{i-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

It’s the sum to infinity of a geometric series the first term of which is $\left(\frac23\right)^i$ and common ratio $\frac 23$